# How do i delete an old image and replace it with another i google storage drive

Tags: laravel, google-drive-api

I wanted to edit a form on my app and every other data where updated including the image but I discovered that the old image was not removed from the google drive folder instead added the new image. please what am I doing wrong in this code?

```
// Check if a new image was uploaded
    if ($this->image) {
        // Delete the old image from Google Drive
        $oldImagePath = $this->grade->image;
        Storage::disk('google')->delete($oldImagePath);

        // Store the new image in Google Drive
        $newImagePath = $this->image->store('/', 'google');

        // Update the image and image URL in the validated data
        $validatedData['image'] = $newImagePath;
        $validatedData['image_url'] = Storage::disk('google')->url($newImagePath);
    }
```

Comment: are you passing the correct file path, probably not !!